# Removing unimportant words (contractions, conjunctions, stopwords) in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to remove contractions from a text file, not necessarily because of the apostrophe, but in my case I don't need these types of words.

I know you can expand them into full words using the contractions package like:

```
import contractions

fixed_conts = contractions.fix(text)
```

However this doesn't remove them. I know I could just make a giant list and do it by brute force but I'm just wondering if there is something more elegant out there, like any package recommendations

Basically an example output of what I would like is:

**Not this**

```
He isn't scrumming with us today - > He is not scrumming with us today
```

**But instead this**

```
He scrumming today
```

Its' a crummy example, but it's basically to help look for unique words, which is part of larger function.

Comment: Sounds like a job for [NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/) and either stopwords or part-of-speech tagging

Comment: What happened to 'with' and 'us'?

Comment: There's the [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/) package for Latent Dirichlet allocation (LDA) which is a topic model that generates topics based on word frequency from a set of documents. You can use the stemming algorithm to clean your text.

Comment: @DeepSpace like I said crummy example, I know they aren't contractions but other parts of the sentence that I don't need which answers G.Anderson I am using NLTK's stop word dict in this case

Comment: @SebastianGoslin perhaps you should update the title and the content of the question. Removing only contractions can be as easy as `fixed = ' '.join(word for word in sentence.split() if "'" not in word)`

Comment: @DeepSpace updated the title, its an awkward question I know

Comment: @Sylhare looking at the documentation now

Answer (score -1):

You could create a list with all the contractions and create a new text that doesn't have any of the words in that list

```
contractions = ["you're", "aren't", ...]
cleaned_up = [word for word in text if word not in contractions]

cleaned_up = " ".join(cleaned_up)
```

Comment: That would be the brute force method, I'm just wondering if anyone has run into something more elegant